# How can I set an app page for a button Firebase In App Messaging Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am trying to customize the button action of Firebase In-App Messaging. ex: You move to a setting screen when you tap a button on Firebase In App Messaging. I know you can set URL on Firebase console but how can I set an app screen(not WebView) for the button. I found that you can customize the message for both iOS and Android. However, I don't see how to customize it in Flutter. Can't I customize it in Flutter? Please help me.